# Angular 5 and :host pseudo class

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class, angular5

I have been using the :host pseudo class in Angular 4 with no problems. We are converting to Angular 5, and now the style does not seem to be getting added to the host component. Is there a different way to add this now in the new version of Angular?

```
:host {
  border: 10px solid black;
  &.isLeft {
    display: flex;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
  :host {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

The isLeft class is set up based on a parameter that is passed into the component from the parent component because this particular control can be displayed in 2 different formats, one of which is responsive. Inside the component, I have the following code:

```
  @HostBinding('class.isLeft') isLeft: boolean; 

  @Input()
  placement: string = 'responsive';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLeft = (this.placement.toLowerCase() === 'left');
  }
```

I know there is a suggestion to use @HostBinding to do all of this. First of all, I'm not sure how that would work when I have to use media queries. Secondly, the only way to use @HostBinding with this would be to include styling inside the component, which goes against our company standards.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
@HostBinding('style.border') styleborder = '10px solid black';
```

define isLeft in css, and put:

```
@HostBinding('class.isLeft') someField: boolean = true;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I am not supposed to have all styles within the scss file, so I don't think using style within @HostBinding will work in this case. I have included all the code above to show the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Code had included

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

Is working now that that is removed.